# How do I pass a value to a constructor in a class with an @Configuration annotation?

Tags: java, spring

I'm new to Spring and I'm trying to figure it out.Let's say I have such a class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.constructordi")
public class Config {
    private String details;

    Config(String details){ this.details=details; }

    @Bean
    public Engine engine() {
        return new Engine("v8", 5);
    }

    @Bean
    public Transmission transmission() {
        return new Transmission("sliding");
    }
}
```

I saw that we get the Bean in this way:

```
ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
Car car = context.getBean(Car.class);
```

That is, out of interest, I added myself to this example (In the example of this class, these lines were not there)

```
private String details;
Config(String details){ this.details=details; }
```

Because it is interesting to understand how we can pass the value there? Do I understand correctly that it will be necessary to use XML in such cases? I will be glad to help

Comment: How would you use `details`? And how would you set it when loading the app context? By answering these 2 questions you'll probably see that this is not a real need to pass this parameter to the `Config` class.

Comment: @GaëlJ So that's why I wrote that I added it myself ,that just out of interest I added how to do this, not for the sake of practical value

Comment: You normally _should not_ "get beans" at all in a Spring application. Please explain your use case in more detail. In most cases of modern Spring applications, you'll use Boot, specify your values with `ConfigurationProperties`, and inject a properties object as a parameter to `@Bean` methods.